# Grid movement of game units

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to achieve a grid movement for a character and enemies. This is what I have so far.

```
public float moveSpeed = 5f;

Rigidbody2D rb;
public Animator animator;

Vector2 movement;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movement.x);
    animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movement.y);
    animator.SetFloat("Speed", movement.sqrMagnitude);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = movement;
}

public void MoverHaciaDelante()
{
    movement.y = 1 * moveSpeed;
}

public void MoverHaciaAtras()
{
    movement.y = -1 * moveSpeed;
}

public void MoverHaciaDerecha()
{
    movement.x = 1 * moveSpeed;   
}

public void MoverHaciaIzquierda()
{
    movement.x = -1*moveSpeed;
}

public void Parar()
{
    movement = Vector2.zero;
}
```

And on the part of the enemies I carry this movement system.

```
private Animator myAnim;
private Transform target;

[SerializeField]
private float speed;
[SerializeField]
private float maxRange;
[SerializeField]
private float minRange;


void Start()
{
    myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    target = FindObjectOfType<Player>().transform;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) <= maxRange && Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) >= minRange)
    {
        FollowPlayer();
    }
}

public void FollowPlayer()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: `movement.x = 1 * moveSpeed;` is not going to do a lot. Rather make it `movement.x += 1 * moveSpeed;`

Comment: I put everyone a +?

Comment: That will help; I'm not quite sure if it's exactly the behavior you are trying to get. But yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078980/grid-based-tile-movement-collisions-in-unity - this might help. Also, there are lots of tutorials on the internet. Even Unity official 2D Roguelike tutorial has grid movement.

Comment: How is the behaviour of this code so far differing from what you want? Remember, we can't see what your game is supposed to be, only what you tell us or show us by including descriptions, images, or animations in your question.